# How to set PHP include_path for php-fpm in nginx config?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php-fpm

I'm trying to migrate from Apache to nginx. In my Apache conf file I had

```
php_value include_path "/home/my-app/topincs/php:/home/my-app/topincs/vendor/php"
```

Now I got

```
fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "include_path=/home/my-app/topincs/php:/home/my-app/topincs/vendor/php";
```

in my nginx's fastcgi_params file, but it seems the include path is not used by php-fm as I'm getting the following error.

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(Response.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/my-app/topincs/docroot/.start on line 3
```

Whereas the file Response.php does exist in the directory `/home/my-app/topincs/php`.

How should I set it so that  php-fpm recognize it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set php values directly in your fpm-pool configuration file like this:

```
php_value[include_path]  = "/home/my-app/topincs/php:/home/my-app/topincs/vendor/php"
```

You don't need to set it in your nginx configuration.

Comment: Can you set the include_path per directory from here?

Comment: I built Nginx and php-fpm from source and I can't see any pool.d directory anywhere. Is this pool configuration related to Nginx or to Apache or both ? Why is your configuration not json like ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be in a pool.d directory, this depends on the distribution. pool configurations are either in php-fpm.conf or included from there. The configuration is related to php, independent from the webserver you're using.